# source code security on TFS

Tags: security, tfs

I have been working with a Visual Studio project by myself for a while. and now we have a new coder with me. We are not sure yet how trustworty he is. so we need to block him to run or read the project source codes if he copied and take it to home or anywhere else except our environment with TFS. How could I do it, is it possible. Regards
EDIT: let me clear some points: I want a source code only available in office environment, in TFS, so developers can do anything with it but when they take it to the home, the solution wont run and display codes)
I am asking if this is possible. or is there any similar approach that I am unaware

Comment: If you don't want him to be able to access the code, how do you expect him to be able to work on it?

Comment: Imagine a guy started to work with you for 2 DAYS, you give him full access the code. Even though you interview him for couple times how can you know how trustworty he is in just 2 DAYS. after a week, you realizes that he is not adaptable to your company culture and let him go. if he take the code with him, I am asking how can you prevent him to have the source code that you invest your year then use it any where else. that was my point

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a people problem, not a technical one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this through TFS. You woul dneed to look at creating a secured desktop/remote session. 
Even if you put him on a desktop that can't be taken home, you will have to disable USB ports etc. etc. so that he can't copy it over to his.her own device.

Comment: Just a heads up Niel, it's considered redundant to sign your posts on Stack Overflow. :)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't supported in TFS and I doubt it ever will. If you are worried about this then you need a tighter interview process. Have them sign non-disclosure agreements and such. Perhaps this is a case of paranoia, however there may be a slight alternative:

Get yourself a public/private key pair from a [CA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) and sign your assemblies with the private key (which is known only to the 'trustworthy' developers or even just 1 of 2 senior members), have your builds compile using this private key (lock down your build server) and publish only these assemblies. Make your customers aware of this and give them your public key.

It will prevent people from stealing and publishing your source code under your name but it's a tremendous effort (and it won't stop them from outright theft and publishing as a competitor). If you are interested start looking up asymmetric encryption with assembly signing.